# Cite a joint statement

Tags: bibtex

How to cite a "[joint statement](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uB4LcQHMVP-oLzIIHA9SjKj1uMd3erGu/view)", with no "representative" author or institution?

This statement is signed by more than 170 scientists from the U.K., sent to NHS, with different affiliations.

Should I just simply use `misc`? In that case, how to address the authors, since the list is sorted in alphabetical order and there are 170+ of them?

Comment: I am not sure that's a TeX question, strictly speaking ... ? I'd suggest checking with your institution, academic advisor, editorial board or whoever else is involved with your writing efforts.

Comment: There are several issues mixed up in your query. In particular, what you put in the fields of an entry of type `@misc` is separate from how the entry is *cited* in the body of the  document. Without knowledge of the specifics of the document you're looking to reference, I'm afraid it's not possible to provide definitive advice. If the declaration indeed lacks representative authors and/or institutions, I would assume it's ok to set `author = {{Joint Statement}}`, as long as you provide sufficient information elsewhere in the entry, say, in the `note` field.